# Maximize Width of TitleView

Tags: ios, autolayout, uinavigationbar, titleview

I'm using a storyboard and added a UIView to a navigation item with 2 sub UILabels. I want the UIView to be the maximum width possible. I noticed that I cannot use auto-layout to create constraints to do this. This means I get results like this.

[image]

Is there a way I can have the titleview automatically resize to fill the navigation bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating the titleview in code. 
First I set the width to the width of the view. Then I set it to autoresizing flexible width.

I set this view as the title view. The navigationbar then automatically resizes the view to the correct size.

I also used the viewWillAppear to set the alpha of the view to 0 and viewDidAppear to fade the view in by setting the alpha to 1. Otherwise you can see the view jump as it gets resized.

Answer (score 0):

You can try dragging the edges of your TitleView to the very far edges of the view so that there is no room in between. Then pinning the edges of the TitleView to the edges of the Superview for your constraints. Next whenever you are wanting to bring this TitleView up you have to hide the previous view that was showing and stop hiding your TitleView. You would have to do this on some sort of IBAction button click or method call. Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for or what exactly your app is doing but hope this steers you in right direction

Comment: The pinning options are disabled for the titleView